# Track Oracle DB Trigger usage

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, statistics

Does anyone know if it is possible to track how often triggers are initiated?
and also check the outcome of the trigger, i.e updates or any error messages that triggers produced?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can add any logging logic you want to the trigger -- you can add an insert to a log table and write the new (`:new.<col>`) and old (`:old.<col>`) values.

You can also use Audit.